# ParseConfig in Parse Beta dashboard does not allow empty string?

Tags: parse-platform

I noticed in the new beta Parse dashboard that when I try to create a String parameter in Parse Config it does not allow me to have an empty value.

The current dashboard allows me to have empty values for String parameters in Parse Config.

Is this just a bug or a change for the future where Strings cannot be empty?